# Verification fields with android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created an app with Fragments (FragmentPagerAdapter) and this app has 4 tabs.

In the last tab I have a "save" button, tha saves all the fields from the tabs.

I'ld like to run a function do validate all the fieds for all tabs. There are a lot of edit text and spinners that I'ld like to check and use Obj.setError(message) on some cases.

It only works if I have 2 tabs or less.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Rod_Algonquin, the answer from Bobbake4 (about setOffScreenPage) works great to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this only works for 2 tabs or less is because by default a view pager will only keep the page directly to the right and left loaded at a given time. You can use [`setOffScreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to change the value to 5 or something to keep those fragments loaded while you swipe around.

You should think about this though, make sure this is the best solution for your situation. It might be better to create a state manager disconnected from the fragments themselves to store the state of the input. You should also take a look at [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) for saving the state of fragments when they are removed by the system.